# Mysql default current_timestamp not storing in 24 hour military format

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `username` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Whenever I insert a record, the created field should be automatically filled with the current timestamp. However, for some reason I keep seeing the inserted timestamp in a 12 hour format. When I do something like `select created from users limit 1;` I would get `2012-04-30 11:34:05`

When I do something like `select current_timestamp` I would get the 24 hour format  `2012-04-30 23:34:05`

When I cast it to unix_time and ask php to convert it to PST time, it's correct. But I would like to have the column be displayed in 24 hour format without any time manipulation. Can anyone help?

Comment: that's just a formatting issue; specify the precise format you require in the select

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Mitch said in the comment above, it seems like just a matter of formatting the output on your `SELECT`. Try [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created, '%Y-%c-%e %H:%i:%s') FROM users
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I just realized I been unnecessarily explicitly setting default timestamps in my model classes with an incorrect time  `date('Y-m-d h:i:s')` instead of `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`